# How to share functionality between subclasses

Tags: scala

I would like subclasses to inject functionality within the base class' apply method:

Base class:

```
case class BaseClass(data: Json)

object BaseClass {
  def apply(data: String) : JsonClass = {
    try {
      _ //subclass functionality should go here
    } catch {
      case e: Exception => ErrorJsonClass(data)
    }
  }
}

object SubClass extends BaseClass {
  def apply(data: String) : Json = {
    deserialize(data) // this should be called within the base class' apply
  }
}
```

Is there a way to do this without declaring separate methods within the  base class?

Ie. Im trying to avoid the following:

```
object BaseClass {
  def apply(data: String) : JsonClass = {
    try {
      convert(data)
    } catch {
      case e: Exception => ErrorJsonClass(data)
    }
  }

  def convert(data: String): JsonClass = _
}

object SubClass extends BaseClass {
  def convert(data: String) : Json = {
    deserialize(data) 
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to extend an object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7625040/is-there-any-way-to-extend-an-object)

Comment: Why would you like to avoid "the following"? "The following" is exactly what you should do, only instead of doing `def convert(data: String): JsonClass = _`, you should declare it abstract, i.e. `def convert(data: String): JsonClass` (no implementation)